# Error when deploying to Google Cloud for Ruby: "Not enough VMs ready"

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

I have been receiving the following error when trying to deploy a ruby application to Google Cloud Platform:

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml
Beginning deployment...
...
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying).
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fix**: remove `.bundle/config` and `vendor` and run `bundle install` rather than `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

Something with running bundler with `--path vendor/bundle` was breaking the container being built in the cloud. I found this by looking at `crash.log` in the log viewer and finding a line where the required gem was missing. I can only assume this has to do with differences between the platform runtime and my local environment.